# Why don't we circulate system air to compressor for cooling?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics

I understand that most refrigerators and air conditioners work on refrigerant fluid being transported inside tubes and take heat from inside and "export" it outside at the heat exchanger.

Why though, do we use refrigerant fluid for this? Can't we just send air from the system through a suction valve system into a compressor OUTSIDE the system? The compressor will the do work on the air, pressurizing it and let it reach ambient temperature. Then the high-pressure ambient-temperature air is let in the system through another valve. As far as I understand, the pressurized air will have to expand as pressure of the air inside is lower. In order to do this, it will take internal energy of to-be cooled air particles and expand! This should lower the average energy of the system's air particles compared to before this cycle... cooling!

Point out my misunderstandings, I'm all in for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the correct understanding about the functioning of the refrigerator. The phenomenon you have stated is known as the Joule - Thomson effect. This effect cannot be observed in all fluids. Also different fluids have different change in temperature for the same pressure drop. This is the main reason why we choose a particular refrigerant which will give us the highest efficiency (more cooling for same work done). Before taking in heat, the fluids are in their liquid state and after accepting heat turn into vapours. Since latent heat of vaporization is much higher than heat capacity, we take advantage of this state change.
Thus we require a fluid which can be liquified at room temperature and has high latent heat of vaporization.

These are the main factors which makes air a poor refrigerant. Also we will not have control over the quality of air entering in the device. The air outside may be too hot, acidic or dusty and may damage or cause malfunctioning of the refrigerating system. By isolating the cycle of refrigeration we make them more reliable and efficient in performance and power consumption.

Comment: I can't vote this enough. Thank you!